# Header template and title

Tags: string, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, header

Let say that we have the above xaml in wp7 platform:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="MainPanorama">
    <controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="Panorama1" TabIndex="1">
        <controls:PanoramaItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="12,70,0,-30">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Header1" Text="Downloader" FontSize="50" Margin="-5,-70,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </controls:PanoramaItem.Header>

        ///////////////////////////////
        other xaml code like grids and other

    </controls:PanoramaItem>

    ///////////////////////////////
    other xaml code like PanoramaItems

</controls:Panorama>
```

How can i get the TextBlock.Text (string) of Header1, notice that i want something dynamically as i have many PanoramaItems and i want to get header of every PanoramaItem dynamically like an array of MainPanorama.

I have tried this:

```
PanoramaItem gen_panorama = MainPanorama.SelectedItem as PanoramaItem;
gen_panorama_head = Convert.ToString(gen_panorama.Header);
```

but there is no Header as the header is in template of every PanoramaItem, how can i get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with 'Binding' header data template!

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="MainPanorama">
    <controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="12,70,0,-30">
                TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" Margin="-12,-70,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" />
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>

    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Here any we want" x:Name="Panorama1" TabIndex="1">
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```